# 2-way ANOVA for time series analysis

Tags: time-series, anova

I am currently working with RNA-Seq data for my undergraduate thesis. I am trying to investigate the role of a transcription factor during zebrafish development. I have two strains of fish, AB and KO with data collected at time points 2 hpf (hours post fertilization), 48 hpf and 96 hpf. I want to see differential gene expression across all three time points between the strains and was told that I should do 2-factor-ANOVAs (I tried other time course modules such as betr and because my time points are too far apart, the modules cannot obtain covariances that allows it to run). However, I have no idea what to do next. Do I do a 2-factor ANOVA between time and strain and look for strain and interaction effects? Or do I do a 1-way ANOVA between two time points but only looking for strain effects? I apologize if this is vague and would be available for elaboration.